# Apache rewrite module https to https with different port not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, port, apache2.4

I am trying to rewrite the port of an incoming request in Apache(running through XAMPP) but no matter what I do, it just doesnt work.
I want to redirect all incoming requests like this from -
https://qr-radec-minus.dot/cp.tms.fe/services/M0780UPPQueryPort?wsdl
to
https://qr-radec-minus.dot:16262/cp.tms.fe/services/M0780UPPQueryPort?wsdl

Below are the different rewrite module rules that I have tried in vain -

`RewriteRule ^/(?!qr-radec-minus\.dot)(.*) https://qr-radec-minus.dot:16262$1`

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^qr-radec-minus\.dot$ [NC]        
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://qr-radec-minus.dot:16262$1 [R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^qr-radec-minus\.dot:443$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://qr-radec-minus.dot:16262/$1 [L,R=302]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^16262$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)cp\.tms\.fe/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:16262/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^/(?!qr-radec-minus)(.*) https://qr-radec-minus.dot:16262/$1 [R,L]
```

Thankz in advance!

Comment: Where are you putting these directives? What other directives do you have? What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Malformed redirect? Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below, Clear cache beforehand. I am not using any matched group I am aligning incoming request_uri to the new port forwarded url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://qr-radec-minus.dot:16262%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It is working [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=484f2311-58b2-5338-9150-16ee0c78e466).